Pine Script for personalized strategy
I need a script for back testing my strategy, can someone help in this regards.
Trade Entry - in Nifty 50,  15 minutes chart, when 09:15 TO 09:30 candlestick high gets break and closes above the high, Sell PUT  at the money strike price on current week expiry and hedge with Buy PUT at the money strike price on Monthly expiry.
OR
If 09:15 TO 09:30 candlestick low gets breaks and next candle closes below low then sell CALL at the money strike price on weekly expiry and hedge with Buy CALL at the money strike price on Monthly expiry
stop loss 100 points and Target 300 points
NA
